# Why HABTM relation entries are not cleared after a destroy in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-postgresql

I was wondering why I have to write this (following) code to clear the relation table after destroying one of the two elements joined in a HABTM relation in Rails (using 5 here).

```rb
class Model < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :things
  before_destroy :clear_habtm

  private

  def clear_habtm
    things.clear
  end
end
```

Wouldn't it be simpler if Rails did this automatically ?
What do you think about it ?

Comment: Dont use `HABTM` if want to destroy dependent objects

Comment: You don't want to destroy other `Thing` that is referenced by some other `Model`

Comment: It won't destroy the other `Thing`. `clear` will only remove the join table entry to avoid ghosts entries.

Comment: when you do `Model.first.things = Thing.first(2)` rails will automatically destroy other entries. You don't have to worry about it

Comment: or even `Model.first.thing_ids = [1,2]`

Comment: And when I want to add entries like this ? `Model.first.things << thing`. It is kinda common to only add a relation instead of setting all at once. The real point is, I do not want any ghost entry